# Make error: commands commence before first target

Tags: gcc, makefile

Makefile:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -D__XMLSEC_FUNCTION__=__FUNCTION__ -DXMLSEC_NO_XSLT=1 -DXMLSEC_NO_XKMS=1 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -DXMLSEC_CRYPTO_DYNAMIC_LOADING=1 -DXMLSEC_CRYPTO=\"openssl\" -DUNIX_SOCKETS -DXML_SECURITY -DDEBUG

LDFLAGS= -lcrypto -I/usr/include/libxml2 -lxml2 -I/usr/local/include/xmlsec1 -lxmlsec1

$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) src/aadhaar.c src/uid_auth.c -o AuthClient
```

I'm getting this error: `error: commands commence before first target`

Comment: Format your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to miss the target definition:

```
AuthClient : src/aadhaar.c src/uid_auth.c 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) src/aadhaar.c src/uid_auth.c -o $@
```

Comment: Thanks Maxim.
Just one more thing..When I try to 'make' now, it shows  
fatal error: xmlsec/xmlsec.h: No such file or directory. I tried installing the libxmlsec1 as well as xmlsec1 packages but it error continues. I looked into system include directory and as expected it was not there irrespective the packages got installed. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @AshishK It is make error or compiler error? It is more likely the latter. You need to install that library and have its headers in the standard include paths or in additional location specified with `-I<dir>` compiler option.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that it's a Compilation error. I have already searched the relevant packages through dpkg-query and have installed all related packages. Still not getting why libxmlsec or xmlsec is showing up in the "system include" path. I hope the final solution to this compilation error would lie here to search for the package and nothing else!

Comment: @AshishK Ask another question, someone may help.